# What's wrong with the trust policy on my aws role that it can't be assumed cross-accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

My lambda, named 'configure-idp' runs as role 'configure-saml-providerA' in account AAAAAAAAAAAA.  I need to assume role 'configure-saml-providerB' in account BBBBBBBBBBBB which has permissions to configure the ipd for account BBBBBBBBBBBB.  The trust on 'configure-saml-providerB' looks like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::AAAAAAAAAAAA:assumed-role/configure-saml-providerA/configure-idp"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

And yet, when my lambda attempts to run the `assume_role` command (see below), I get:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::AAAAAAAAAAAA:assumed-role/configure-saml-providerA/configure-idp is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::BBBBBBBBBBBB:role/configure-saml-provider
```

The `assume_role` code mentioned above is:

```
client = boto3.client('sts')
        assumed_role_object = client.assume_role(
            RoleArn = f"arn:aws:iam::BBBBBBBBBBBB:role/configure-saml-providerB",
            RoleSessionName = "LambdaSetIDPSession"
        )
```

I've also tried changing the principal ARN in the trust to look like this:

```
arn:aws:sts::AAAAAAAAAAAA:role/configure-saml-providerA
```

But get the same error.

Why am I not able to assume role `arn:aws:iam::BBBBBBBBBBBB:role/configure-saml-providerB` when the trust on that role is set to allow me to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following

https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-assume-role-error/

Maybe you're part of an aws organization and there's an SCP that's restraining you to assume role?

Comment: Thank you @Mathias-lagomarsino.  I am in fact part of an organization, however there is no SCP to prevent role assumption.  Thank you for the valuable suggestion.  Perhaps other users running into this situation will find that solves their problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I used the account alias instead of the account id in the ARN when trying to assume role.  You wouldn't see that in the post bc I obfuscated the sensitive information.